# Why cannot I use a string variable of Django in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, django

I'm currently learning Django/Python. I'm trying to use Django variables in html or javascript, which doesn't work as I desire.
My models.py, and views.py files  look like

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Students' name is a string variable, like "Tanaka" or "Yoshida", and password is an integer variable, 1234 or something like this.

views.py

```
def index(request):
    all_students = Student.objects.all()
    context = {'all_students': all_students}
    template = loader.get_template('aaa/LogIn.html')
    return render(request,'aaa/LogIn.html', context)
```

the script code in LogIn.html file looks like

```
<script>
{% for student in all_students %}
        alert({{student.name}})
{% endfor %}
</script>
```

I want to use student.name in this code, but this doesn't work. If I change student.name to student.password, it works as expected. The question is why student.password appears in an alert message while student.name doesn't. I think the problem may be related to the variable type of name and password. 
How can I use Django variable in this case? Thank you, in advance.

Comment: `alert("{{student.name}}")` — you have to **quote** strings in JavaScript.

Comment: I'd really suggest you don't store passwords in a charfield... if you're making a custom user model then you should follow the django docs..

Comment: This web site is not something Im creating for job or anything serious. So, passwords are not actually a password. Still, thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
alert("{{student.name}}");
```

Inject variables in string.